# Center stacked-images horizontally

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to display 4 images centered in the screen. I need this images must be stacked one of top another. I resolved the stack part:

```
.img-container { position: relative;  }

.img-container .top {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

<div class="img-container">

    <img src="icon-1.png">
    <img class="top" src="icon-2.png">
    <img class="top" src="icon-3.png">
    <img class="top" src="icon-4.png">

</div>

<div >
    <img class="img-responsive center-block " src="another-image-below.png"
      style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
</div>
```

That gives me the 4 images stacked BUT now I need to center all 4 of them (horizontally). The "another-image-below.png" is just another image that it is also centered but  that must be placed below the 4 stacked images.
It sound simple, and I tried everything but I cannot resolve it.
How can I achieve that?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
https://jsfiddle.net/b5p8dkcu/4/

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the z-index in your example, unless you have another element somewhere that has to be behind the images.

You can just add `align="center"` to the `<div align="center" class="img-container">`.

EDIT:

```
<html>
<style>

.img-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.top {

}
```

```
<div align="center" class="img-container">

    <img src="icon-1.png">
    <img class="top" src="icon-2.png">
    <img class="top" src="icon-3.png">
    <img class="top" src="icon-4.png">

</div>

<div >
    <img class="img-responsive center-block " src="6.png"
      style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;">
</div>
```

If you need them to be vertically on top of each other:

```
<style>
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.top {
 display: block;
}
```

If you need them to be literally on top of each other:

```
<style>
.img-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.top {
position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: You are right, I dont need the z-index. But adding align="center" only center the first image ("icon-1.png") maybe its because the other image has "position: absolute". I also edit my code, i had a copypaste error (the image that sit over the icon-1 must have the "top" class).

Comment: Like so:
`.img-container {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}`

HTML:
`<div align="center" class="img-container">`

Comment: Well, like you said, you changed your example/code :) Don't place the styling at the `.top` element but only at the `.img-container` and `position: relative;` on the container. Then add `align="center"` to img-container and you will have the content centered.

Comment: First of all thanks for helping me. I did what say but the images dont stack anymore. Altough there are centered.

Comment: No problem :) Okay, so I'm not sure I understand what you mean by stack. If they have to be on top of each other, so that you can only see one of them, then you add `position: absolute;`to the `.top` styling. If you need them to display under neath each other, you add `display: block;`to the `.top` styling. Hope this gets you what you want :)

Comment: Yes, by stack I mean that they have to be on top of each other. Adding "position:absolute" to the ".top" style only "stack" the images that has the "top" class. I added a fiddle in my post to show this.

Comment: I'm afraid you lost me a bit.. If you cannot add a class to all the elements in the `.img-container` ,  I would style the children of the `.img-container` with the `>` operator. E.g: `.img-container > img { /* some styling */ } ` this would style all the img "children" in the `.img-container`.