# Image text proper display

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I am facing an issue with my orientation in the [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaMHI.png)react app.
I want the matter to be in a line horizontally.
So, please help to do this.

Comment: Please include you code so we can help you...

Comment: Heya, this is pretty general and kind of confusing.  I'll post some very general answers to your very general question.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52785326/center-stacked-images-horizontally) addresses some of what you are looking for... it might be good to include a [minimum repro example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) somewhere like [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)

Comment: This is css issue, but I can't help you further because I don't know what mistakes you made. Would be helpful if you post the css, or code sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

My guess from what you are saying is that you want to stack the images horizontally instead of vertically.

[Flexbox is great for this](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-poincare-j394r?file=/src/App.tsx